# one nginx virtual host config http2, why all Virtual Hosts change to http2?

Tags: nginx, http2

request https://a.cool.com

request https://b.cool.com

both https request's https protocol change to http2.

Why?

My config:

```
server {

...

litsen 443 ssl http2;

server_name a.cool.com;

...

}

server {

...

listen 443 ssl;

server_name b.cool.com;

...
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2

Comment: what does the certificate say? does it include both a.com and b.com? in such case http/2 allows connection coalescing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I enable HTTP/2 for specific virtual hosts only on Nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987592/can-i-enable-http-2-for-specific-virtual-hosts-only-on-nginx)